# How to add a column of string constants via DolphinDB metaprogramming?

Tags: metaprogramming, dolphindb

My SQL statement is as follows:

`select col1,col2,"ABC" as col3 from ..`

`col3` is a constant string.

How to implement this SQL query via DolphinDB metaprogramming? I have tried `sqlCol("ABC")` or `parseExpr`, but they all treat "ABC" as a column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the argument passed to `sqlCol` is *colName*. The string "ABC" needs to be included in a metacode, which can be achieved by `sqlColAlias` and `parseExpr` with the following script:

```
sqlColAlias(<"ABC">,"col3")
parseExpr(" `ABC as col3")
```

The output is:

```
< "ABC" as col3 >
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sqlColAlias([<col1>, <col2>, <"ABC">], `col1`col2`col3)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34284417)

Comment: @AwkwardCoder Please pay attention when reviewing. This is not a link-only answer. And although code-only answers are generally frowned upon, they are answers. Downvoting would be the appropriate action, not voting to delete.